# Enable agenda in the calendar widget

Tags: calendar

When i click the date widget in the top bar, the calendar pops up.

In the calendar, you can click to select a day. The day will be highlighted

Question: 
              how to add an event and eventually have reminders ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

double clicking on the date in the applet opens up the calender. then in the top left fand there is `New`.Click on it and select what u want.

Comment: I tried, it does **not** open the calendar. Maybe I should install a package ?

Comment: try installing evolution

Comment: Thanks ! After install, lauching evolution, rebooting, double clicking in a date of the calendar applet opens evolution.